# Flex image wrapper add empty space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have `flexbox` with images at 100% height. I don't understand why there is an empty space in the `flexbox` element. I haven't used margin or padding.

You can see:

The image in chrome debugger is **all good**, height 100%, width keep aspect ratio:

[image]

But it has an empty space. The width of the `flexbox` does not equal the image width.

What I should do to make the image width the size of the flexbox?

[image]

```css
img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666;
}

.attach {
  height: 100%;
}

.attaches {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}

.root {
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="root">
  <div class="attaches">
    <div class="attach"><img src="url"></div>
    <div class="attach"><img src="url"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***Update 1:***
sandbox:
https://jsfiddle.net/w50f61us/
[image]

Comment: I don't see that extra space, is there anything I am missing? https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/4k8gd3ym/27/

Comment: @Manjuboyz i add sandbox "Update 1"

Comment: btw what are you trying to do with the code? what is you need?

Comment: i need remove empty space. image wrapper size should equal image size (without extra empty space). On screen you can see extra space blue painted.

Comment: That's because the height and width you used for images, each images are different resolution and it takes space, you have to define width and height and align it with flex.

Comment: i do adaptive by height item. Size of images i dont know

Answer (score 0):

```
Simply make width of the image is 100%. it will cover your entire div

// here image takes height and width according to their size 

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666;
}

but if you want to image to cover your entire div make it width 100%

img {
  max-height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px #666;
}
```

Comment: dont work . in second example i get lose keep aspect ratio  https://i.ibb.co/Bn9MdWw/lose.png

Comment: may i know image height and widht size